# Grouping variables based on conditions

Tags: python, loops, dataframe, group-by, conditional-statements

Grouping the following data in 64 groups. I have two variables x and y for each object. I would like to group them up based on a condition. Both x and y have a range between 0 and 2000 and I want to break them into 64 groups. The first one to have x<250 and y<250 the next one 250

```
Sample data:
index x y
1     10 100
2     270 60
3     550 1000
4     658 1900
5     364 810 
6     74  1890
...
6000  64  71
```

Could you please tell me a way to do it? I have my data now as a data frame but I do not know if it the way to go. I was told by some colleagues to avoid using loops in data frames. I attached also a picture of how my scatterplot looks like, it could be helpful to visualize my data for you. Thank you in advance!

[image: Example of the data I have]

Comment: Nothing is clear could you re-frame your question add sample data and be specific on what you need

Comment: To use conditionals with pandas, you can try df2 = df1[df1.iloc[:,0] > something]

Comment: I am sorry I didnt notice,it should be better now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pd.cut()` to bin your variables to `x`- and `y`-categories and then construct their group according to some logic (depending on if you want a specific order, my code below simply orders the cells from bottom to top and left to right)

```
bins = [250 * i for i in range(9)]
labels = list(range(8))
df['x_bin'] = pd.cut(df['x'], bins, labels=labels)
df['y_bin'] = pd.cut(df['y'], bins, labels=labels)
df['group'] = df['x_bin'].astype(np.int8) + df['y_bin'].astype(np.int8).multiply(8)
```

Note that the `.astype(np.int8)`-calls are a workaround to allow for basic math with `pandas.Series`. If you don't want to store the intermediate binning assignments, all of this could be done in one line by substituting the column references in my last line for the assignments in the prior lines:

```
df['group'] = pd.cut(df['x'], bins, labels=labels).astype(np.int8) + pd.cut(df['y'], bins, labels=labels).astype(np.int8).multiply(8)
```